# sending more than 1 addresses to solidity function

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to send more than 1 addresses as parameters to solidity function but I am getting error while 1 address is working fine. Here is my web3 code :

```
feeval = (Math.random() * (0.0090 - 0.0110) + 0.0110) * 1e18;

sttcontract.methods.getAirdrop(s1,s2).send({from:addr, value: feeval}, (err, res) => {
  if(!err) console.log(res);
      else console.log(err);
});
```

and solidity function :

```
function getAirdrop(address _s1, address _s2) public payable returns (bool success){
    aComm1 = 10;
    aComm1 = (msg.value * aComm1) / 100;
    address(uint160(_s1)).transfer(aComm1);
    address(uint160(_s2)).transfer(aComm1);
}
```

the same code with 1 address is working fine.

Comment: Can you check if the `s2` is a valid address (starting with `0x`, following 40 hex characters, ...), and not `null`, `undefined` or any other invalid value? ... Also, does your contract have enough balance to send the `aComm1` value to both addresses (i.e. does it have at least `aComm1` * 2)?

Comment: yes, I have checked it several times, it is a valid address, not null and fee is enough cause in s1 only 10% is transferring.

Comment: What is the error? How does the function work when you pass only one address (what are the effects of running the function with one address passed)? did you check if the solidity function works as intended eg. in remix.ethereum.org ?

Comment: @Eternal, finding that error because Metamask throws error only.